# problem when executing "pub global run flutter_plugin_tools format --plugins"

Tags: dart, flutter

When executing pub global run flutter_plugin_tools format --plugins
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

I receive this error:

> D:\Android-Project\flutter\FORK\plugins>C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub global run flutter_plugin_tools format --plugins name_plugin
>
> Downloading Google Java Format...
>
> Formatting all .dart files...
>
> CreateProcessW failed 2
>
> Unhandled exception:
>
> ProcessException: The specified file could not be found.